Error while installing pyqt-tools on Python 3.12.3
I attempted to install PyQt5 and PyQt6. In both cases, PyQt itself was installed normally, but PyQt-Tools (5 or 6) gave the error "metadata-generation-failed". My Python version is 3.12.3, and I am using pip 24.0.
Error:
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      pyproject.toml: line 7: using '[tool.sip.metadata]' to specify the project metadata is deprecated and will be removed in SIP v7.0.0, use '[project]' instead
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n4nrn3uv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 46, in build_wheel        
          project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n4nrn3uv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 92, in bootstrap
          project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n4nrn3uv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 587, in setup
          self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9w45o5_u\pyqt6_13c3263a185a4827a4df706f02c146f6\project.py", line 60, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n4nrn3uv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 51, in apply_user_defaults
          super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n4nrn3uv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
          self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
        File "C:\Users\Artem\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-n4nrn3uv\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 50, in apply_user_defaults
          raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
      sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I only found out on the Internet that I needed the latest version of Python (which I already have), and that PyQt5 is not compatible with M1 on Mac (I have tried to install both the fifth and sixth versions, and in addition, I have a laptop with Windows and Intel).

The first thing to check when a package/module/etc fails to install is to verify its compatibility. As also shown by the current answer by user16171413, none of pyqt[5-6]-tools currently support Python above 3.9, and as the related pypi package pages explain, macOS support is incomplete. The easy (but not so much) path would be to downgrade your Python, but that may not be possible or preferable (and it may still not work at all due to the incomplete macOS support noted above). What do you need that package for?

You may have to downgrade your python because both pyqt5-tools and pyqt6-tools supports Python 3.5 - 3.9.
Also it is recommended to use virtualenv or venv to create isolated environments to install your dependencies in.

Please try to use proper anchors whenever they exist, as ScrollToTextFragment is currently just a proposal, not an established standard (yet).

@musicamante okay, I've taken note of that
